# outlook 2010 auto inviting attendees

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

I'm wondering if there's any way of a meeting request being sent to TWO calendars for approval.

our workplace has a room that has a dividing wall which can be removed for large meetings, we currently have a booking calendar for each room, but when both rooms are needed, our users will oftentimes only book one room, which means someone may have to go and remove the dividing wall at a moment's notice

I think the best way forward is to set up this user as an approver for the room bookings, but it doesn't solve the problem of users only booking one room, so what we need is a way of booking BOTH rooms via ONE calendar, and then the user can approve or deny the second room based on the needs of the meeting.

is this even possible or is there another option we could pursue?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have 3 objects named **Room A**, **Room B** & **Both Rooms** or something along those lines.

**Room A** could be one side of the room.

**Room B** could be the other side.

**Both Rooms** is obviously both the rooms (or the one room without the divide).

If a user wants the **A** part of the room he/she can book the **Room A** etc.

A new object can be created on Active Directory. IT Department should know how to do that.

Comment: I am actually IT haha, we had thought of that, but getting people to actually use it in the way we wish would prove difficult, which is why I arrived at the above solution, I'm just not sure 1: if it's possible or 2: how I would implement it, and google has been no help this time!

Comment: Hmmm. . . Depending on how big your organisation is - user training may be effective. **1:** Training users on how and what to select when booking a meeting would be useful. Only then will they use this to the way you want. **2:** Of course it's possible. All you need to do is create three new objects on Active Directory, then create three new mailboxes relating to the new objects you have created. BOOM - done! (obviously a few more configurations here and there) Let me know if you need help with the Active Directory stuff.